# getting old file from google drive not the updated one into android

Tags: android, file-upload, download

i have implemented a project in android where users backup and restore a file from google drive.

however there is a issue like it doesn't download updated file from the google drive. also i can see updated file in google drive but while downloading old file is fetched. Please kindly suggest me a solution.

this is my code

```
  if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
                        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
                        // failures.
                        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
                        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Myportfolio.this)
                                 .addApi(Drive.API)
                                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(Myportfolio.this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(Myportfolio.this)
                                .build();
                    }
mGoogleApiClient.connect();

 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {
            if (!status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("SYNCING", "ERROR" + status.getStatusMessage());
            } else {
                Log.e("SYNCING", "SUCCESS");
                // execute async task to list AppFolderContents

            }
        }
    });
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "backup.txt"))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {


                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {

                    if (result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() > 0) {
                        resu = String.valueOf(result.getMetadataBuffer().get(0).getDriveId().getResourceId());
                        Log.d("Value of id", resu);
                        // resu = resu.substring(resu.indexOf(":"));
                        if (status == 1) {
                            Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient, resu).setResultCallback(idCallback);
                            Log.d("Google:", "update");
                        } else if (status == 2) {
                            Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient, resu).setResultCallback(idCallback1);
                            Log.d("Google:", "fetch");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                            Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
                            Log.d("Google:", "create new");
                        }
                    }
            });



}

final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
           Log.d("file status:","Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        DriveId driveId = result.getDriveId();
        DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
        new EditContentsAsyncTask().execute(file);

    }
};
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    //showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");

                    return;
                }
                final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

                // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // write content to DriveContents
                        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                        try {
                            writer.write(resultSet.toString());
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }

                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("backup.txt")
                                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                .setStarred(true).build();

                        // create a file on root folder
                        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                    //    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");

                    return;
                }
                // showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Backup to cloud done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(Myportfolio.this, "Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("File Id: ", String.valueOf(result.getDriveFile().getDriveId()));

            }
        };


public class EditContentsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DriveFile, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(DriveFile... params) {
        DriveFile file = params[0];
        try {
            DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                    mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();

            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return false;
            }
            DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(resultSet.toString().getBytes());
            com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status =
                    driveContents.commit(mGoogleApiClient, null).await();
            return status.getStatus().isSuccess();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while appending to the output stream", e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
            // showMessage("Error while editing contents");
            return;
        }
Log.d("Update: ", "Done");
        // showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
    }
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback1 = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {
        new RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask().execute(result.getDriveId());
    }
};

public class RetrieveDriveFileContentsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DriveId, Boolean, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(DriveId... params) {
        String contents = null;
        DriveFile file = params[0].asDriveFile();
        DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult =
                file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
        if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
           return null;
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            contents = builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while reading from the stream", e);
        }

        driveContents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);



        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
           // showMessage("Error while reading from the file");

            return;
        }
      //  restoregoogle=result;
        try {
            if (result == null) {
                return;
            }




            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Restored from cloud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
Log.d("Data from Cloud: ", result);

       // showMessage("File contents: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code, logcat logs so that others can understand your procedure

Comment: this is my code, it works for adding new file, updating (though sometimes it does nothing for the first time). however while downloading old file is downloaded, not the updated one.